# Count paired columns and aggregating

Tags: r, count, dplyr

I have a dataframe which links two factors such that:

```
X       Y
A1      B2
A2      B3
A5      D6
B2      A1
B3      A2
```

And I would like to count the paired occurrences such that:

```
 i      j      Count
 A1     B2       2
 A2     B3       2
 A5     D6       1
```

As you can see the order of column *i* and *j* doesn't really matter. I have tried with `table` and `dplyr` using group_by and summarize(Count = n()) but I cannot make it work because it counts each paired independently so it doesn't aggregate A1-B2 and B2-A1.

I would really appreciate some suggestion as it is a relatively easy task but not trivial for my research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` with margin 1 to sort rowwise, and then use `table` function to count, i.e.

```
table(apply(df, 1, function(i)toString(sort(i))))

#A1, B2 A2, B3 A5, D6 
#     2      2      1
```

**NOTE:** You can wrap the result in `data.frame` and manipulate the output to fit your needs

Comment: Thanks! Straightforward solution! +1